# How to stop Next duplicating HTTP requests for my project? Huge payloads affecting performance

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

Been really loving Next so far but I'm running into this issue where my static requests are being duplicated( as per first screenshot below from page speed insights--this is also just a subset of what's happening as it's also duplicating CSS files).

I couldn't figure out why this is happening so I created a fresh new next project and the same issue is happening (screenshot 2 directly from inspecting browser and looking at the individual network requests).

The new project is extremely minimal with barely any code. I made sure that I'm not importing anything twice or in different places. What could be causing this to happen? (For reference, I copied most of the code to Gatsby/Firebase and when I deployed it, this issue doesn't happen even though it's almost exactly identical code).

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

[image: First Screenshot]

[image: Second Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this issue, as of this moment this is a bug to do with the automatic preloading prop of the  component from Next.js.